# Import Cardinality Mismatch Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I have a main app and a plugin. The main app is exporting an `IHost` object and the plugin is importing an `IHost` object. I ran mefx and it recognizes both of those. But when I do `/causes` on the plugin it gives me a ImportCardinalityMismatchException. My container sees the plugin, but when I call `Me.container.getExports(of IController)()` it doesn't return anything.

My Controller looks like this:

```
Class Controller 
   Implements IController   
   ' ...
    <Import()>
    Public Property Host As Lazy(Of IHost)
   ' ...
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to `<ImportMany()>` in my plugin. Then for the variable I was importing to I needed to make it `IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of IHost))` Or use `Lazy(of IHost)` if you want to do a `<Import()>`